# boost::property_tree::write_json() cannot open file

Tags: c++, exception, boost, boost-propertytree

This is the code that I use to write the boost property tree structure into a file

```
void writeConfigurationFile(std::string filePath, boost::property_tree::ptree &configurationTree)
{
    try
    {
        boost::property_tree::write_json(filePath, configurationTree);
    }
    catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path &e)
    {
        LOGGER_EXCEPTION(std::string("boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path => what:").append(e.what()).c_str());
    }
    catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_error &e)
    {
        LOGGER_EXCEPTION(std::string("boost::property_tree::ptree_error => what:").append(e.what()).c_str());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        LOGGER_EXCEPTION("Exception occurred in writing Configuration file");
    }
}
```

I am getting an exception

LOGGER_EXCEPTION: boost::property_tree::ptree_error => what:configuration.json: cannot open file.

However I can see that the file is very much present there. Is there a reason why this would fail?
Also are the exceptions that I am catching correct ?

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the file?

Comment: yes. I do. Also the file seems to be getting updated inspite of throwing the exception.